# Read in avro file with boto3 and convert to string (Python)

Tags: python, boto, avro, boto3

I'm using boto3 to read in an avro file from my s3 bucket.
However, I'm stuck on how to actually convert the avro to a string.

```
avro_file = file_from_s3.get()['Body'].read()
```

After getting to this step, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: So you read the object and store as bytes variable. What have you try so far? did you try print(avro_file)? What's is your python version?

Comment: using python2.7

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. You need to use StringIO from python and download_fileobj() from boto3.

```
import boto3
import StringIO
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

output = StringIO.StringIO()
latest_file_object = s3_client.Object('bucket_name','latest_file')
latest_file_object.download_fileobj(output)

reader = DataFileReader(output, DatumReader())
for r in reader:
    print r
```

Comment: This will only work on python 2, `download_fileobj` explicitly asks for a byte interface and the avro examples also show opening in binary mode. You could use `BytesIO`, but have you tried just passing in the body object?